# Using getattr in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The `getattr` function is defined as follows:

> **getattr(object, name[, default])**
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise `AttributeError` is raised.

Which method does `getattr()` call? For example, does it call:

- `__getattr__`
- `__get__`
- `__getattribute__`
- something else?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__  and below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getattr()` goes to `__getattribute__()` first, same as the dot operator:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __getattr__(self, obj):
...         print("Called __getattr__")
...         return None
...     def __getattribute__(self, obj):
...         print("Called __getattribute__")
...         return None
...     def __get__(self, obj):
...         print("Called __get__")
...         return None
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foobar
Called __getattribute__
>>> getattr(a, 'foobar')
Called __getattribute__
```

Convention is to use `getattr()` only when you don't know at compile-time what the attribute name is supposed to be. If you do, then use the dot operator ("explicit is better than implicit"...).

As @Klaus D. mentioned in a comment, [the python Data Model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) goes into more detail about how `.__getattribute__()` and `.__getattr__()` interact. Suffice it to say that, at a high level, the latter is a fall-back option of sorts for if the former fails. Note that `.__getattr__()` and the built-in `getattr()` are not directly related - IIRC this is a quirk of naming that originated in earlier versions of python and was granfathered into python 3.