# Using `functools.partial` and `map` with built-in `getattr`?

Tags: python-3.x, functools

I apologize if am completely missing something obvious or if I have not dug into the documentation hard enough, but after 30 mins or so I found a work around (without having understood the error I was getting) and ... hence the question here. Suppose I have a class:

```
class RGB(object):
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        super(RGB, self).__init__()
        self.red = r
        self.blue = b
        self.green = g
```

and I define a list of `RGB` instances as follows:

```
from random import random
rr, gg, bb = [[random() for _ in range(20)] for _ in range(3)]
list_of_rgbs = [RGB(*item) for item in zip(rr, gg, bb)]
```

why can't I extract a list of `red` values by doing:

```
from functools import partial
*reds, = map(partial(getattr, name="red"), list_of_rgbs)
```

or

```
*reds, = map(partial(getattr, "red"), list_of_rgbs)
```

I know I can make it do what I want by saying `reds = [x.red for x in list_of_rbgs]` but that would be difficult if the list of attributes to extract comes from elsewhere like: `attribs_to_get = ['red', 'blue']`. In this particular case I can still do what I want by:

```
reds, blues = [[getattr(x, attrib) for x in list_of_rgbs] for attrib in attribs_to_get]
```

but my question is about what causes the error. Can someone explain why, or how to make it work using `partial` and `map`? I have a hunch it has something to do with [this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533959/using-getattr-in-python) (and so maybe the partial function needs a reference to `self`?) but I can't quite tease it out.

For reference I was on Python 3.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial can only set positional arguments starting at the first argument. You can't set the second argument as positional, but only as a keyword argument. As the first one for `getattr` is the object, it won't work well together with `map` and `partial`.

What you can use however is `operator.attrgetter()`:

```
from operator import attrgetter
*reds, _ = map(attrgetter("red"), list_of_rgbs)
```

Comment: I didn't know about `operator.attrgetter`. That seems to be a handy module. I should have understood what I was trying to do is exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173660/can-one-partially-apply-the-second-argument-of-a-function-that-takes-no-keyword).